# Orthogonality and Linear independence infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a doubt, in a Hilbert space it is known that if I have $ \{x_k\}_{k=1}^n$ vectors in a finite space and these n elements are orthogonal then are linear independent. Is it true for a space of infinite dimension when if $(x_k, x)=0$ $\implies $ $x=0$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear independence in vector spaces of infinite dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616518/linear-independence-in-vector-spaces-of-infinite-dimension)

Comment: As long as the vectors are non-zero, orthogonality implies linear independence in ANY inner product space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is apparent that the space is an *inner product space*, say $H$ and that the given vectors, say $\{e_k\}_{k\in I}$ for some indexing infinite set $I$, are *mutually* orthogonal. To that end, then *yes*, it is true that $H$ is infinite-dimensional ( what, however, is *generally not true* —in contrast to the $n$-dimensional case—is that $H=span\{\hat{e}_k\}_{k\in I}$, where $\hat{e}_k$ is the unit vector in the direction of $e_k$; even $span\{\hat{e}_k\}_{k\in I}$ may not be isomorphic to $H$.)