# I wanna know about a theorem of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

Is there some theorem that says that if the number of vectors of a base $S$ is less than the dimension of a vector space $V$ than it cannot span the vector space?

Comment: $S$ can not be called a *base* if its cardinality is less than the dimension of your vector space.

Comment: It follows from the fact that [all bases must have the same cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52667/proof-that-two-basis-of-a-vector-space-have-the-same-cardinality-in-the-infinite). In fact, if $S$ spans $V$, then there is a subset of $S$ that is a basis of $V$, by taking a linearly independent subset that is maximal by inclusion. But since the dimension of $V$ is strictly larger, then it has a basis of that larger cardinality, which is a contradiction.

Comment: How about the *definition* of dimension?

Comment: @amd: While the fact of equal cardinality of bases is essential to the definition of dimension, it is a theorem/proposition that needs proof that "dimension" is well-defined in this context.

Comment: @hardmath If you’re throwing around a term like “dimension,” there’d better be a definition of it already. That definition usually involves the minimal cardinality of a spanning set. This question puts the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 2):

I suuppose that you're after this:

**Theorem:** If $V$ is a vector space, if $S\subset V$ and if $\#S<\dim V$, then $\operatorname{span}(S)\neq V$.

Yes, this is a standard Linear Algebra theorem.

**Proof:** I will assume that $\dim V<+\infty$. If $S\subset V$ and $\operatorname{span}(S)=V$, then, if $S'$ is a maximal linearly independent subset of $S$ such that $\operatorname(S')=V$ (it must exist, since $S$ is finite), $S'$ is a basis of $V$. Therefore$$\#S\geqslant\#S'=\dim V.$$

Comment: Can you show a proof for this theorem ?

Comment: @Faisal I've added one.