# Does this theorem stand for subspaces with infinite dimensions?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

There is a theorem that states for a finite dimensional non zero vector space $V$ if {$D^1,D^2$} are bases for subspace $M$ of $V$ such that {$D^1$} and {$D^2$} are also a non zero set of vectors in $M$.   then {$D^1$} and {$D^2$} have the same number of vectors which makes sense. I couldn't find anything about subspaces with infinite dimensions but I assumed that this won't hold true because, for example, if we have {${D^1}$} with infinite number of independent vectors and {${D^2}$} with finite number of independent vectors then {${D^1}$} and {${D^2}$} will form the bases for $M$ but the number of vectors in  {$D^1$} and {$D^2$} are not the same. First, am I correct to assume this and second is my reasoning correct? thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your question, although I *think* I know what you want to ask. For example: "if $\{D^1,D^2\}$ is a bases for a subspace $M$" --- Are $D^1$ and $D^2$ elements of $M$ or subsets of $M$? Part of the problem is that $\{D^1,D^2\}$ is a single mathematical object, and thus "is a" seems to be confirming that you're talking about a single mathematical object (e.g. a set containing two elements), but then "bases" is plural, which now contradicts my initial reading. Look back over what you've written -- proof/edit some -- and perhaps be more explicit with what the symbols represent.

Comment: Another example: "then {$D^1$} and {$D^2$} have the same number of vectors" --- $\{D^1\}$ is a set that contains exactly ONE element, and $\{D^2\}$ is a set that contains exactly ONE element, so obviously they have the same number of elements. I don't have to know what $D^1$ and $D^2$ are to conclude this, although from what you've said (but maybe did not intend to say), $D^1$ and $D^2$ are vectors.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thank you for the feedback. I have edited the question. forgive me because I have trouble with English language. perhaps I did not understand the concept.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: [Proof that two basis of a vector space have the same cardinality in the infinite-dimensional case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52667/13130)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It does help very much indeed and I see where I got it confused. Thank you!