# If $G$ has finite codimension, then $G$ has a complement

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces

Two [Hamel bases](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hamel_basis#Definition) of the same vector space have [the same cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52667/proof-that-two-bases-of-a-vector-space-have-the-same-cardinality-in-the-infinite), so we define the dimension of a vector space as the [cardinality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition) of one of its [Hamel basis](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hamel_basis#Definition).

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Let $G$ be a closed subspace of $E$. A subset $L$ of $E$ is said to be a *(topological) complement* of $G$ if $L$ is a closed subspace of $E$ such that $G\cap L = \{0\}$ and $G+L=E$.

I would like to confirm that

> If $G$ has finite codimension, then $G$ has a complement.

Could you have a check on my below understanding?

---

Let $n := \operatorname{codim} G < \infty$. By [rank-nullity theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752056/does-the-rank-nullity-theorem-hold-for-infinite-dimensional-v?rq=1), $n + \dim G = \dim E$. Let $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ be a Hamel basis of $G$. Then there is a linearly independent set $(e'_i)_{i=1}^n$ such that $(e_i)_{i\in I} \cup (e'_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a Hamel basis of $E$. Let $L := \operatorname{span} (\{e'_1, \ldots, e'_n\})$. Then $L$ is the required complement of $G$.

Comment: Looks fine to me. You should add that a finite dimensional subspace of $E$ is closed due to the fact that all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent. Hence $L$ is complete, therefore closed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you so much for your verification!

Comment: Using the rank nullity theorem when dimensions are infinite tends to require care...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see. In my below answer, I don't mention cardinality anymore. Do you think it's fine now?

Comment: I understand that the codimension of a subspace $L$ of $E$ is the dimension of the quotient space $E/L.$ This space is isomorphic to $G,$ where $G$ is a complement space. Since $\dim G +\dim L=\dim E,$ we get that ${\rm codim} \,L+\dim L=\dim E.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I'm sorry, but could you explain the purpose of your previous comment?

Comment: There was a comment  of yours asking me to take a look at some related post. I do not see this comment anymore. So I will delete my previous comment.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ah Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have a recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703950/is-i-s-in-my-attempt-of-fredholm-alternative-injective) about Fredholm alternative. If you don't mind, please have a look at it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the quotient map $J:E \to E/G$. Let $B_1$ be a basis of $G$. Let $B_2$ be a basis of $E/G$. By [rank-nullity theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752056/does-the-rank-nullity-theorem-hold-for-infinite-dimensional-v?rq=1), $B_1 \cup J^{-1} (B_2)$ is a basis of $E$. Notice that $B_1 \cap J^{-1} (B_2) = \emptyset$. Then $L := \operatorname{span} (J^{-1} (B_2))$ is the required complement of $G$.