# If $E \subset F$ then $\dim(V/F) \le \dim (V/E)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Two [Hamel bases](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hamel_basis#Definition) of the same vector space have [the same cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52667/proof-that-two-bases-of-a-vector-space-have-the-same-cardinality-in-the-infinite), so we define the dimension of a vector space as the [cardinality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition) of one of its Hamel bases. I'm trying to verify that

> Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $E,F$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $E \subset F$. Then $\dim(V/F) \le \dim (V/E)$.

Could you check my below attempt?

---

We consider the map
$$
f:V/F \to V/E, x + F \mapsto x + E.
$$

Let's prove that $f$ is injective. Let $x,y\in V$ such that $f(x+F)=f(y+F)$. Then $x+E=y+E$. Then $x-y \in E$. Then $x-y \in F$ since $E \subset F$. Hence $x+F=y+F$. It's clear that $f$ is a homomorphism. The claim then follows.

Comment: If this map was well defined, it would also be surjective as well, right? Since $x + E$ will be mapped to by $x + F$.  As such I don't think this map is well-defined, and I would suggest a similar map in the opposite direction.

Comment: You would also need to show that if $x+F=y+F$, then $x+E=y+E$, to show the map is well-defined, and you are going to have a bit of a problem proving that... I mean, consider the case of $E=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and $V=F$. Your definition does not yield a well-defined function, let alone and injection.

Comment: Instead, consider the map going the other way, and use Rank-Nullity.

Comment: No, the correct conclusion is $\dim(V/F)\leq\dim(V/E)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It's my bad... Thank you so much for your and Daniel's help!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have a recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703950/is-i-s-in-my-attempt-of-fredholm-alternative-injective) about Fredholm alternative. If you don't mind, please have a look at it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arturo and Daniel pointed out in their comment, the correct map should be
$$
f:V/E \to V/F, x + E \mapsto x + F.
$$

Let's prove that $f$ is well-defined. Let $x,y\in E$ such that $x+E=y+E$. Then $x-y\in E$. Then $x-y\in F$ since $E \subset F$. Then $x+F=y+F$. Then $f(x+E)=f(y+E)$. Clearly, $f$ is linear and surjective. By [rank-nullity theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752056/does-the-rank-nullity-theorem-hold-for-infinite-dimensional-v), we get $\dim (V/E) = \dim (V/F) + \dim (\ker f)$. The claim then follows.